# Wrong google maps api position on my html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an issue when I want to center the map on my website.
Here is my JS:

```
function initMap() {
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 5
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="popup_map">
    <div class="map-container">
        <div id="map" class="g-map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#popup_map {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         z-index: 1050;
         display: none;
     }

    .map-container {
        width: 98%;
        height: 90%;
        background: white;
        margin: 2% auto;
    }

    .g-map {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

The marker is on the good positon but the map is not well centered.
The center of the map should be on the marker but instead it is on the red dot...

[image]

edit : no issue on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evqygdtp/)

edit2 : and to show the map I just added a simple link, here is the JS I used :

```
$("a#show_map").click(function () {
        $("#popup_map").fadeIn();
    });
```

This is exactly where I added this to make it work :

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044));
```

Comment: seems like your code somewhere is resizing the map container div so that it loses its center.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (**in the question itself**).  If you can't reproduce the issue on jsfiddle, then you haven't provided the problematic code. (the `#popup_map` has `display:none`, how/where are you changing that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resize the map

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

If needed you have to reCenter the map aswell. for that you have to do

var reCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
map.setCenter(reCenter);

Comment: did you try recenter the map with your lat and lang values

Comment: Thank, just after the resize (to show the map), I recenter it via : map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044));